# Building glibc with -finstrument-functions

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, glibc, instrumentation

I'm trying to log the calls made by an app prior to a crash, including libc calls. I've used the `-finstrument-functions` support in gcc with my own libs but I can't build glibc with this instrumentation.

I added `-finstrument-functions` to `libc_extra_cflags` in libc/configure but the build fails with "undefined reference to __libc_multiple_libcs"  when linking ld.so.
 Just running `CFLAGS=-finstrument-functions ./configure` doesn't work because the configure tests fail since they don't define `__cyg_profile_func_enter/_exit`.

I'm currently trying to figure out how to add instrumentation per module (stdlib, io, string, etc) and looking through libc/foo/Makefile's it should be possible using e.g. `CFLAGS_stdlib = -finstrument-functions` but the flag doesn't show up in gcc commands.

Is there a way to add per-module flags to the glibc build, or is glibc known not to work with -finstrument-functions ?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to log the calls made by an app prior to a crash, including libc calls.

You can use [ltrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) to trace calls made by the application to any shared library, including GLIBC.

> is glibc known not to work with -finstrument-functions

Pretty much.

If you think about it, what is your `__cyg_profile_func_enter` going to do? It can't call into libc, or you'll end up with infinite recursion. It's possible to use direct system calls, but it's far from trivial.